# psql could not connect to server after complete reinstallation [Ubuntu 21.10 / PostgreSQL 13]

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

After experiencing issues related to the existence of two different PostgreSQL versions installed on the same machine, I decided to `remove --purge postgresql*` and reinstall postgresql-13. Now the output of `psql --version` is `psql (PostgreSQL) 13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-1)`.
However, trying to enter psql, I have this error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I tried the several solutions proposed on similar posts but none solved my issue.

Edit : output of `pg_lsclusters` is

```
Ver Cluster Port Status                Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down,binaries_missing postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
13  main    5433 online                postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
```

Comment: To your question add the output of `pg_lsclusters`.

Comment: Done! Original post edited.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -a /var/run/postgresql`?